# Am I able to use classes in HTML to go from a section to a different section in the same page?

Tags: html

How am I able to go from a section to another section on my HTML page when clicking on a button.

I have seen that it is possible with ID's. You create and ID somewhere and call it in your href with # and then the ID name.

I tried this with classes too. I created a class, and tried to call it in my href with . and then the ID name.

It didn't work. Am I able to do this inside the HTML page with classes too, and if so how would I be able to do that?

Comment: Please don't post only text, but also provide some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you answer your question: you can go to different HTML tags with `<a href="#id" />` but not with class, since you can have many `div` with same className in the page, while `#id` is usually unique for each div.

Of course you can scroll to a `<div>` by className using Javascript, but what is the expected behaviour ? Do you want to scroll to the first `<div>` matching the className, or the last `div`, or do you want to do something else ?

Lastly, if your problem can be solved using `#id`, you should just stick with it: className usually represents style, but should not be used for functional behaviour.